# Сбросить div по confirm

Tags: jquery-ui

Есть таблица, с кучей ячеек (календарь), в последней строке таблицы одна ячейка, в которой есть несколько div'ов. JS-Код:

```
$(function(){
  $("div.champ").draggable({
      containment: 'table.calendar',
      snap: 'table.calendar td.drop',
      snapMode: 'inner',
      revert: 'invalid',
      cursor: 'move',
      scroll: false
  });
  $("table.calendar td.drop").droppable({
      accept: "div.champ",
      drop: function(event, ui){
                if (confirm("Сохранить:\nID События: "+ui.helper.attr("id")+"\nна дату:"+$(this).attr("id")+"?")) alert("Сохранено");
            }
  });
});
```

Суть вопроса в чем... при подтверждении "Сохранено" выводит - все отлично. А как сделать так, чтоб при отмене div возвращался в последнюю строку таблицы и не "дропался"?

Comment: лучше confirm вынести в отдельный метод и вызывать drop при confirm true

Comment: ну логично да, но тогда суть droppable() вообще ломается. Как вызывать confirm? По mouseup? при этом проверять еще над каким элементом кнопку отпустили... Это мне кажется слишком замудрено получается

Comment: а если confirm false и и вернуть false в drop? или же по confirm false делать reset объекта...

Comment: return false в drop ничего не дает. Т.е. объект все равно дропается

Comment: тоже не работает :( к тому же после этого div перестает быть draggable, а курсор остается **move**

Comment: ну блин =// тогда топорно можно попробывать если false то удалить из дума див и заного воткнуть с биндингом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тогда по confirm false попробуйте $("div.champ")[0].reset(); или просто  $("div.champ").reset(); если champ тот самый див

Comment: Не сработало, но уже не актуален вопрос. Просто надо было принять.